# When I add my .gdb folder in QGIS my raster files don't open properly

Tags: qgis, raster, file-geodatabase

[image]

When I drop my folder on layers panel, all data are imported but my raster that in a complex polygon convert to a rectangle and some tables.

This is my file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TQuFtU4CVCULXooPRmcI2Lzlg7MYYnRA/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Witch version of QGIS do you use ? I did try in QGIS 3.34 and it work fine (I get the two raster and one polygon layer)

Comment: It used to be that GDAL  and QGIS  couldn't read rasters in a gdb.  But times change so look at https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/openfilegdb.html for GDAL.  You may need to update your QGIS to the current version.